# all possible phase combination

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a list of

> 1,1

and it can take either + or - sign. So the possible combination would be 2 to the power 2.

```
 1  1
 1 -1
-1  1
-1 -1
```

Similarly, I have a list of

> 1,1,1

and it can take either + or - sign. So the possible combination would be 2 to the power 3.

```
-1   1  -1
-1   1   1
 1   1   1
 1  -1   1
-1  -1  -1
 1   1  -1
 1  -1  -1
-1  -1   1
```

In python, how can I do that using itertools or any other methods. Any help please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [1,1,1]
>>> for xs in itertools.product([1,-1], repeat=len(lst)):
...     print([a*b for a,b in zip(lst, xs)])
... 
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, What if lst = [1,2,3]?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, If the list contains only 1s, no need to zip().

Comment: @falsetru Why wouldn't you need to zip? Don't you have to index both lists with `a, b`? You'd have to zip right?

Comment: @CornSmith, Do you mean  [lst[i]*xs[i] for i in range(len(lst))]  /  [lst[i]*x for i,x in enumerate(xs)]? I prefer zip() version.

Comment: @falsetru Hoho those are verbose! No I thought that Ash was asking what `zip` was being used for at all. I didn't realize that e was talking about the output of `product` being the same with and without `zip`ing. But you're right, if the input wasn't [1,1,1] it would be necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
from itertools import combinations
size = 3
ans = list(set(combinations([-1,1]*size,size)))
#[(1, 1, -1),
# (-1, 1, 1),
# (-1, -1, 1),
# (1, -1, -1),
# (1, -1, 1),
# (-1, 1, -1),
# (1, 1, 1),
# (-1, -1, -1)]
```

This approach also gives the same result with `permutations`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try a solution without imports:

```
list_input = [1,1,1,1,1]
permutations = 2**len(list_input)
for p in range(permutations):
    if p: # if not first iteration
        mod = 1
        for k, v in enumerate(list_input):
            mod = mod/2.0 # needs to use modulus in steps
            if not p % (permutations * mod):
                list_input[k] *= -1
    print(list_input)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, 1, 1, -1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
[1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
[1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, -1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, 1, 1]
[1, -1, -1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, 1, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1, -1, 1]
[-1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

How fun.